# How to make lower() method work for a read file

Tags: python, string, methods

In python, I am having a file read then trying to convert everything to lower case but it isn't changing.  What am I doing wrong?

```
fstor = open(txt)
story = fstor.read()
story.lower()
```

OUTPUT ( I cleaned up punctuations and other marks )

The days went by and the wisest little pig's house took shape brick by
brick From time to time his brothers visited him saying with a chuckle
Why are you working so hard Why don't you come and play But the
stubborn bricklayer pig just said no
I shall finish my house first It must be solid and sturdy And then I'll

Comment: Do you want the changes **saved** in the file? Then you need to **write** to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are **immutable** in `python`

```
fstor = open("file.txt")
story = fstor.read()
#story.lower() #strings are immutable in python
data = story.lower() #return a new string with lowercase
print(data)
```

### Output:

```
the days went by and the wisest little pig's house took shape brick by brick from time to time his brothers visited him saying with a chuckle why are you working so hard why don't you come and play but the stubborn bricklayer pig just said no i shall finish my house first it must be solid and sturdy and then i'll
```

### Write the data to another file

```
with open("file.txt") as fstor:
    story = fstor.read()
    data = story.lower() #return a new string with lowercase

    with open('another_file.txt','w') as afile:
        afile.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('directory_path.txt', 'r') as f: 
    text = f.read() 
 
text = text.lower()
print(text)
```

works this code :)